# Facebook white screen issue loading fbGraph API in webView?

Tags: iphone, xcode, facebook-graph-api, fb-graph

I am facing a strange issue: I am using the **fbGraph API** to get Facebook related data,
when I load Facebook to log in, in my `webView` it shows blank white screen.

Has anyone had this issue before? Does anyone know how to resolve it?

I have searched a lot on Google but everyone is talking about clearing the browser cache in Safari, Firefox, Chrome and cookies, no one has talked about the **iPhone browser** or the **fbGraph API**.

Any help would be appreciated.